# How to put properly an angle or a bracket at the front or on the top of a box?

Tags: positioning

I try to find a simple way to put an angle or a bracket at the front or on the top of a box. I use the math commands `\left[` , `\left\{` etc because they have the same thickness and look well.  I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\begin{document}baseline \_ 
$\left[ \rule[0ex]{3cm}{4cm}\right.$
\end{document}
```

My problem is that with my method the brackets are not placed exactly at the front or on the top but go under the baseline. How one could fix the position of bracket? Is there a simple way to put brackets, angles, parenthesis  or other shapes to any (math, text or image) object  respecting its dimensions?

Comment: You can use `\raise`  to adjust the height of a box.  So `\raise 0.56ex \hbox{[}` would get you a bracket sitting on the baseline, but what are you trying to achieve?  There may be a simpler way.

Comment: @Thurston I tried raise but how much should I raise? If I raise the bracket it will go higher than the upper left corner of the box. My question is somehow general. Actually, I have a problem trying to put some comments with  a bracket at the middle front of some geometrical objects. I don't want to use many package like tikz or similar..Just a simple idea how to put a nice bracket .at the front of the box with the same height.

Comment: @Thurston I tried the following code

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}


\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
\def\boxx{\left[ \rule[0ex]{0cm}{2.1cm}\right.}
baseline \_ $\raisemath{1.9cm}{\boxx }$ \rule[0ex]{3cm}{4cm}
The problem is that  I can not automate this code to any possible figure..